# Django raw query gives none value

Tags: python, django, sqlite, nonetype

I have a questionnaire. I like to get the value of a row with raw query but when I loop through in my HTML file it gives me just the first value but the rest 11 gives me `none` so my addition oft the values also gives me `none`.  I can't understand what am I doing wrong. I made this operation many before on the same way and worked great.

I have 12 questions that I made with html input (not Django forms) for certain reasons, but it works well and it posts the values to the database where I have all the positive and negative values.

**models.py**

```py
class Vezetoi(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user_name)

    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    vezetoi_v01 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v02 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v03 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v04 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v05 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v06 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v07 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v08 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v09 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v10 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v11 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v12 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```py
class VezetoiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vezetoi
        fields = ['vezetoi_v01', 'vezetoi_v02', 'vezetoi_v03', 'vezetoi_v04', 'vezetoi_v05', 'vezetoi_v06', 'vezetoi_v07', 'vezetoi_v08', 'vezetoi_v09', 'vezetoi_v10', 'vezetoi_v11', 'vezetoi_v12' ]
```

**views.py** - I didn't copied some parts here that are useless in this case

```py
def detail(request, item_id):
    item = Vezetoi.objects.get(pk=item_id)

    #VEZETŐI TESZT
    vezetoi_hatekonysag = Vezetoi.objects.raw('SELECT ID, vezetoi_v01 + vezetoi_v02 + vezetoi_v03 + vezetoi_v04 + vezetoi_v05 + vezetoi_v06 + vezetoi_v07 + vezetoi_v08 + vezetoi_v09 + vezetoi_v10 + vezetoi_v11 + vezetoi_v12 AS hatekonysag FROM stressz_vezetoi WHERE id= %s', [item_id])

    context = {
        'item': item,
        'vezetoi_hatekonysag': vezetoi_hatekonysag, 

    }

    return render(request, 'stressz/detail.html', context)
```

**details.html**

```
  {% for i in vezetoi_hatekonysag %}
  <td>{{ i.hatekonysag }}</td>  
  
  <p>{{ i.vezetoi_v01 }} {{ i.vezetoi_v02 }} {{ i.vezetoi_v03 }} {{ i.vezetoi_v04 }} {{ i.vezetoi_v05 }} {{ i.vezetoi_v06 }} {{ i.vezetoi_v07 }} {{ i.vezetoi_v08 }} {{ i.vezetoi_v09 }} {{ i.vezetoi_v10 }} {{ i.vezetoi_v11 }} {{ i.vezetoi_v12 }} </p>
  {% endfor %}
```

The result (query words are just placeholders)

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Why do you even need a raw query for such a simple annotation? You get those `None` values because you never select those columns in your query.

Comment: I don't need it for the annotation. Those are jut for check the values but I will not need them. I use row query for the addition of column values in the row because I am more familiar with SQL language than Django's query language. But I don't understand. What do you mean on I never selected the columns?

Comment: `SELECT ID, vezetoi_v01 + vezetoi_v02 + vezetoi_v03 ...` I don't see you selecting those columns in this query anywhere. As a side note once again your model schema doesn't appear to be normalized (search up on database normalization a bit). The values `vezetoi_v0x` being repeated and allowing null values means that they should be in their own separate table instead of having so many columns for them.

Answer (score 0):

You get those values as `None` in the template because your select clause does not select those columns at all. Moving further there is no need for a raw query for such a simple purpose, you can simply use `annotate` to do this:

```py
from django.db.models import F


def detail(request, item_id):
    item = Vezetoi.objects.annotate(
        hatekonysag = F('vezetoi_v01') + F('vezetoi_v02') + F('vezetoi_v03') + ...
    ).get(pk=item_id)
    context = {
        'item': item,
    }
    return render(request, 'stressz/detail.html', context)
```

Now in the template you can simply write:

```
<td>{{ item.hatekonysag }}</td>  
  
<p>{{ item.vezetoi_v01 }} {{ item.vezetoi_v02 }} {{ item.vezetoi_v03 }} {{ item.vezetoi_v04 }} {{ item.vezetoi_v05 }} {{ item.vezetoi_v06 }} {{ item.vezetoi_v07 }} {{ item.vezetoi_v08 }} {{ item.vezetoi_v09 }} {{ item.vezetoi_v10 }} {{ item.vezetoi_v11 }} {{ item.vezetoi_v12 }} </p>
```

> **Note**: Your model schema is very repetitive and your fields have `null=True`? Perhaps it is better to have a separate model that stores
> these values and has a `ForeignKey` to `Vezetoi to make a one-to-many
> relation.